# Why can't I delete my user accounts in my web application on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my first Rails application, and I'm a beginner programmer. One of the things I let people do who sign up for my app is delete their accounts. Right now, I can delete an account I create on my local environment, but on Heroku, when I try to delete the user account, I get an error saying 'something went wrong'. Here's all of the code that I think is relevant:

My delete_account route in routes.rb:

```
match '/delete_account', to: 'users#destroy'
```

My destroy method in users_controller.rb:

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    cu = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_customer_token)
    cu.delete
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

My link in app/views/users/edit.html.erb:

```
    <%= link_to 'Delete Account', @user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

When I check my Heroku logs, there are no errors. The only error I can find is one about there being no route to load my favicon.ico file. If you can help me fix the problem and help me get the functionality working in my app where a user can delete himself or herself, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have rails js included in your page?

Comment: `@user` is not a path, what html do you get?

Comment: Sidenote, your stripe token deletion should be done in a model's callback

Comment: @apneadiving I think I have rails.js included in my page. I've been precompiling my assets for Heroku with the command 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' and then adding the compiled assets to my git repo. Would that have an effect on it? For the html output when I click the link, all I get is the error message on my Heroku app, but on my local environment, the path does its intended job.

Comment: @user1483441 did you ever figure out the solution to this problem....?